# How to convert negative byte value to either short or integer?

Tags: java, integer, byte, short, typeconverter

We have a file which contains byte array in particular format like header and then followed by data. This file is generated by another java program and then we are reading that same file through another java program in the same format in which it was written.

The program which is making that file, populates `lengthOfKey` as byte which is right as that's what we need as shown below.

```
    for (Map.Entry<byte[], byte[]> entry : holder.entrySet()) {
        byte typeKey = 0;

        // getting the key length as byte (that's what we need to do)
        byte lengthOfKey = (byte) entry.getKey().length;
        byte[] actualKey = entry.getKey();
    }
```

Now as `byte` can only store maximum value as `127`, we are seeing for some of our record `lengthOfKey` is coming as negative while we read the file as shown below:

Program which is reading the file:

```
byte keyType = dis.readByte();

// for some record this is coming as negative. For example -74
byte lengthOfKey = dis.readByte();
```

**Now my question is :** Is there any way I can find out what was the actual length of key because of that it got converted to `-74` while writing it. I mean it should be greater than `127` and that's why it got converted to `-74` but what was the actual value?

I think question would be how to convert negative byte value to either short or integer? I just wanted to verify to see what was the actual length of key because of that it got converted to negative value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the original length from `entry.getKey().length` is greater than `255`, then the actual length information is lost.  However, if the original length was between `128` and `255`, then it can be retrieved.

The narrowing conversion of casting to `byte` keeps only the least significant 8 bits, but the 8th bit is now interpreted as `-128` instead of `128`.

You can perform a bit-and operation with `0xFF`, which will retain all bits, but that implicitly widens the value back to an `int`.

```
int length = lengthOfKey & 0xFF;

lengthOfKey (byte = -74): 10110110
```

Widening it to an `int`, with sign extension:

```
lengthOfKey (int = -74): 11111111 11111111 11111111 10110110
```

Masking out the last 8 bits as an `int`:

```
length (int = 182): 00000000 00000000 00000000 10110110
```

That will convert a negative `byte` back to a number between `128` and `255`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I am able to decode the data and I can see the actual length what it was. Can you explain me why you said this? `If the original length from entry.getKey().length is greater than 255, then the actual length information is lost.` And why it will be lost? Just for my understanding purpose.

Comment: If you received a length of `0`, then it's indistinguishable in `byte` form from `256`.  `0` in binary is 00000000, `256` in binary is 1 00000000, but that `1` is lost when the narrowing conversion to `byte` takes place, and it appears as `0`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), it provides a number of [unsigned math utilities](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PrimitivesExplained), including [`UnsignedBytes`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedBytes.html).

```
UnsignedBytes.toInt(lengthOfKey);
```

Notice their implementation of [`toInt()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedBytes.html#line.67) is exactly what @rgettman suggests.

Answer (score 1):

To convert an assumed unsigned byte to an int.

```
int value = (byteValue >= (byte) 0) ? (int) byteValue : 256 + (int) byteValue;
```